# How to use DataReader with GridView in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datareader

I'm trying to use DataReader in GridView
rather than using DataAdapter.

But I have this error in aspx :

> Non-invocable member 'IDataItemContainer.DataItem' cannot be used like a method

I have the error in this line :

```
<%# Container.DataItem("Data1")%>
```

I have this code :

```
SqlConnection baglan=new SqlConnection("connectionstring text");
if (connection.State== ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    baglan.Open();
}
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Data1 from Table1",baglan); 
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = dr;
GridView1.DataBind();

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="ID" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
<Columns>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>                            

            <%# Container.DataItem("Data1")%>

        </ItemTemplate>

        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="50px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</GridView>
```

How can I fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `Eval`. But the error you posted has nothing to do with using `DataReader`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# Eval("Data1") %>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```